# Sending data to php using wget

Tags: php, linux, unix, wget, uptime

I am trying to hit a PHP url and post some information about my linux box using a cron job and wget.

```
*/30 * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://ping.xxx.com/xxx/up.php?mac=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/HWaddr/ { print $5 }`\&uptime=`uptime`\&ip=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet addr:/ {sub(/addr:/, "", $2); print $2 }`;
```

on php side i am tryint to get request parameters like mac, uptime and ip but i am only able to record mac. Reason i think is because uptime command has `23:42:10 up 22 min,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.04` as output which may be breaking the wget process. I am getting following message when i run wget

```
wget: not an http or ftp url: 23:42:10
```

Can someone please tell me how to pass parameters correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
*/30 * * * * wget -O http://ping.xxx.com/xxx/up.php?mac=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/HWaddr/ { print $5 }`\&uptime=`uptime`\&ip=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet addr:/ {sub(/addr:/, "", $2); print $2 }` /dev/null;
```

You are putting /dev/null where wget expects the url, you just have to switch /dev/null and the url

Answer (score 0):

You can get the uptime in seconds from `/proc/uptime`:

`cut -d " " -f 1 /proc/uptime`

Answer (score 0):

```
 ?mac=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/HWaddr/ { print $5 }`
\&uptime=`uptime`
\&ip=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet addr:/ {sub(/addr:/, "", $2); print $2 }`;

Add quotes
                                                 V
 ?mac=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/HWaddr/ { print $5 }'`
\&uptime=`uptime`
\&ip=`ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet addr:/ {sub(/addr:/, "", $2); print $2 }'`;
                                                                         ^
```